# When I push a 24-karat gold bar with my finger, what subatomic physics are at play?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, solid-state-physics, atomic-physics, pauli-exclusion-principle

I chose a pure gold bar to eliminate the possibility of any chemical reactions occurring, the same question would apply to any everyday object like a wooden block or a marble. Or it could apply with any two solids pushing each other.

So, when I push the gold bar with enough force, the gold bar moves away from my finger due to the pushing force from my finger, but what actually causes this force? Is it the repulsion between the outer electrons on the atoms of my skin cell membranes and the outer electrons of the gold atoms on the surface of the bar? If so, how does this happen on a wide scale to create the pushing force? And how do some of my finger prints end up on the gold bar if the two entities (the gold bar and my finger) are completely repelled by each other's electrons? How do the molecules in my skin cells end up on the outside of the giant metallic lattice that makes up the gold bar?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Pauli-repulsion a "force" that is completely separate from the 4 fundamental forces?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44712/)

Comment: If not, please review the "related" answers in the sidebar and edit to ask a single question that's not already been covered (e.g., the nature of skin oil adhesion to a noble metal).

Comment: @Chemomechanics Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't really answer the question fully. I'm not asking how the electrons individually repel each other according to Pauli principle, I was asking if that happens, and how it happens on a wider scale in context of the 'pushing force' experienced between two solids (how do the electrons line up to repel, how do the repelling forces combine to push the object with more or less force, etc.)

Comment: Fun fact, in practice any surface is covered by a few monolayers of water anyway....

Comment: More discussion: [1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/345655/146039), [2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/735505/146039), [3](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/484543/146039), [4](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69317/146039), [5](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69241/146039), [6](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/383397/146039).

Comment: The classical concept of objects having trajectories is not applicable to quantum mechanics. Therefore, personally I don't understand your statement "how it happens on a wider scale in context". I feel that you should try to edit your question so that it becomes clearer what you know/accept and what you are asking.

Comment: In particular, resistance to compression isn’t equivalent to resistance to surface contamination. It would provide helpful clarification if the  question  focused on one or the other (without repetition of the questions linked above).